# Как достать из QuerySet определенный объект

Tags: python, django, queryset

Имеется вот такой views

```
def random_post(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    i = 0
    for post in posts:
        i += 1
    current_post = i
    q = random.randint(1, i)
    if current_post == q:
        q = random.randint(1, i)
        current_post = q
    else:
        current_post = q
    rand_post = Post.objects.filter(id=current_post)
    return render(request, 'blog/random_post.html', {'post': rand_post})
```

Суть в том, что он достает рандомное число исходя из кол-ва постов и потом благодаря .filter достает объект, id которого равен рандомному числу

Только вот элемент достается в `<QuerySet>`. И когда я хочу обратится, к примеру 
`rand_post.title` я получаю ошибку `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Из документации:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)

> filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a single element.

**Смысл:** функция `.filter()` возвращает объект `QuerySet` даже если в нём лишь один элемент. Однако это *множество*, а не нужный Вам объект. Получить один объект из него можно [функцией `.get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get):

```
rand_post = Post.objects.get(id=current_post)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def random_post(request):
    posts = list(Post.objects.all())
    post = random.choice(posts) if posts else None
    return render(request, 'blog/random_post.html', {'post': post})
```

А ещё лучше, чтобы не вытаскивать из базы все посты:

```
import random

def random_post(request):
    count = Post.objects.count()
    i = random.randint(0, count - 1)
    post = Post.objects.all()[i]
    return render(request, 'blog/random_post.html', {'post': post})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите получить конкретное поле из модели с id=current_post, например name, то используйте

```
name = Post.objects.get(id=current_post).name
```